# Что значит личный в личном составе?

Tags: значения, этимология

Что именно означает слово "личный" в словосочетании "личный состав"? Может ли состав быть не личным или просто составом или составом каким-либо другим?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Что именно означает слово "личный" в словосочетании "личный состав"?

It means the same as "person" in "personnel" (as opposed to "materiel" in military slang).

*Личный состав* literally means "personal composition": the total body of persons that an organization or a military unit is composed of.

> Может ли состав быть не личным или просто составом или составом каким-либо другим?

*Руководящий состав* "management", *подвижной состав* "rolling stock", *профессорско-преподавательский состав* "faculty", *полный состав* "full complement", just to name a few.